# Use one class for multiple elements automatically

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

Sorry, I have very little experience using xjc. I have an xsd containing a lot (huderds) of elements like:

```
<xs:element name="foo">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="V" type="xs:anySimpleType" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="bar">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="V" type="xs:anySimpleType" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

They only differ in name. Using xjc I get hunderds of classes like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
public static class Foo {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "V")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
    protected String v;

    public String getV() {
        return v;
    }

    public void setV(String value) {
        this.v = value;
    }
}
```

If I create such class manually and name it e.g. `ElemWithStrAttr`, is it possible to instruct xjc to use this class for all the xsd elements that match the "Element with a single String attribute 'V'" pattern? I mean without having to explicitly name all the xsd elements that should map to this class in some bindings or episode file?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change your xsd so that you create an complex type for the attribute and use that type for every element you can still use the xjc generated files.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="foo" type="VType"/>
                <xs:element name="bar" type="VType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="VType">
        <xs:attribute name="V" type="xs:anySimpleType" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I get this xsd from a third party and can't modify it.

Comment: the xml content does not change with this notation. so while i agree that it is not very common to alter message structures like this, it is a rather safe change. 
Alternative you can use the generated class for the Vtype and the original generated file with all the classes in it and modify the big file so they all se the Vtype class.